# Restore exact innerHTML to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

I'd like to save the html string of the DOM, and later restore it to be exactly the same. The code looks something like this:

```
var stringified = document.documentElement.innerHTML
// later, after serializing and deserializing
document.documentElement.innerHTML = stringified
```

This works when everything is perfect, but when the DOM is not w3c-comliant, there's a problem. The first line works fine, `stringified` matches the DOM exactly. But when I restore from the (non-w3c-compliant) `stringified`, the browser does some magic and the resulting DOM is not the same as it was originally.

For example, if my original DOM looks like

```
<p><div></div></p>
```

then the final DOM will look like

```
<p></p><div></div><p></p>
```

since `div` elements are not allowed to be inside `p` elements. Is there some way I can get the browser to use the same html parsing that it does on page load and accept broken html as-is?

**Why is the html broken in the first place?** The DOM is not controlled by me.

Here's a jsfiddle to show the behavior http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/5/. Open your console.

```
<body>
    <div id="asdf"><p id="outer"></p></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var insert = document.createElement('div');
        var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
        insert.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(insert);
        var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
        console.log(e.innerHTML);
        e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
        console.log(e.innerHTML); // This is different than 2 lines above!!
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: When the page loads it should also change the markup when it is illegal.

Comment: The browser doesn't store invalid markup. It stores the DOM, which it renders from the initial markup as best it can, allowing for the various errors. When you access `innerHTML`, it walks through the DOM *as it exists then* and builds a string representation of it, which will be valid (other than invalid attributes, they keep those; and maybe a couple of other minor things, but not structural errors like the above). So your `stringified` variable should **already** have the error-corrected HTML. [It does on Chrome, Firefox, and IE10.](http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/)

Comment: To expand on what @T.J.Crowder said, there's no way for Javascript to access the original HTML source code. It can only get the DOM, which is the result of interpreting the original HTML.

Comment: @Barmar: LOL, I was **just** adding a comment, since my second-to-last sentence really was half-complete, wasn't it. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a minimal jsfiddle to show what I mean. I don't need the original HTML, I just need to restore the DOM to it's exact current state in the future.

Comment: @SergiuToarca: The content of your question should be **in** your question, not just linked. If an example is necessary, quote it in the question (ideally, use Stack Snippets [the `<>` button], which are an on-site alternative to jsFiddle).

Comment: If that's what you need, your code should do it. The only problem is that event bindings will be lost.

Comment: The fiddle is a bit different from the question. The problem is that the code **and** markup are each, individually, creating an invalid structure. (And **wow**, browsers really do their very, very best to try to help us out, don't they? That `innerHTML` really surprised me.)

Comment: I've simplified the example. It doesn't matter how the DOM came to be invalid. If the DOM is currently invalid, the operation won't restore properly.

Comment: @SergiuToarca: Yeah, my confident "the HTML will already be valid" both is, and isn't, actually true: It's valid, but not in a way that's going to survive what you're doing. Fascinating.

Comment: If you want the original unmodified HTML you can do a HttpRequest on it.

Comment: you can redefine `Element.prototype.innerHTML` with a getter/setter than stores a backup property on the element instance upon setting. something like: http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/8/

Comment: @SergiuToarca _"since div elements are not allowed to be inside p elements"_ How does _"For example, if my original DOM looks like

`<p><div></div></p>`"_ occur ?

Comment: @guest271314 Please see the example in the question.

Comment: @SergiuToarca Yes. If `html` document , utilizing `.innerHTML` will not render `<p><div></div></p>` , how would `<p><div></div></p>` be rendered initially ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate document where initial `html` includes rendered `<p><div></div></p>`  ?

Comment: @SergiuToarca See http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/9/

Comment: @guest271314 Have you tried running the example given in the question (there's a jsfiddle link as well)? It does exactly this by using javascript to construct the broken structure.

Comment: @SergiuToarca See post.

Comment: I think you don't really understand the differences between source code and DOM, for example when you write " My original DOM looks like <p><div></div></p>", it is false...

Comment: @Bartdude Please take a look at the example. At the point when I want to take a snapshot (first console.log), the DOM is not valid html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to be able to save and restore an invalid HTML structure, you could do it by way of XML. The code which follows comes from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93ewka6w/).

To save, you create a new XML document to which you add the nodes you want to serialize:

```
var asdf = document.getElementById("asdf");
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var save = document.getElementById("save");
var restore = document.getElementById("restore");

var saved = undefined;
save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (saved !== undefined)
    return; /// Do not overwrite

  // Create a fake document with a single top-level element, as 
  // required by XML.    
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString("<top/>", "text/xml");

  // We could skip the cloning and just move the nodes to the XML
  // document. This would have the effect of saving and removing 
  // at the same time but I wanted to show what saving while 
  // preserving the data would look like    
  var clone = asdf.cloneNode(true);
  var top = doc.firstChild;
  var child = asdf.firstChild;
  while (child) {
    top.appendChild(child);
    child = asdf.firstChild;
  }
  saved = top.innerHTML;
  console.log("saved as: ", saved);

  // Perform the removal here.
  asdf.innerHTML = "";
});
```

To restore, you create an XML document to deserialize what you saved and then add the nodes to your document:

```
restore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (saved === undefined)
      return; // Don't restore undefined data!

  // We parse the XML we saved.
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString("<top>" + saved + "</top>", "text/xml");
  var top = doc.firstChild;

  var child = top.firstChild;
  while (child) {
    asdf.appendChild(child);
    // Remove the extra junk added by the XML parser.
    child.removeAttribute("xmlns");
    child = top.firstChild;
  }
  saved = undefined;
  console.log("inner html after restore", asdf.innerHTML);
});
```

Using the fiddle, you can:

1. Press the "Add LadyGaga..." button to create the invalid HTML.
2. Press "Save and Remove from Document" to save the structure in `asdf` and clear its contents. This prints to the console what was saved.
3. Press "Restore" to restore the structure that was saved.

The code above aims to be general. It would be possible to simplify the code if some assumptions can be made about the HTML structure to be saved. For instance `blah` is not a well-formed XML document because you need a single top element in XML. So the code above takes pains to add a top-level element (`top`) to prevent this problem. It is also generally not possible to just parse an HTML serialization as XML so the save operation serializes to XML.

This is a proof-of-concept more than anything. There could be side-effects from moving nodes created in an HTML document to an XML document or the other way around that I have not anticipated. I've run the code above on Chrome and FF. I don't have IE at hand to run it there.

Comment: cool. I'll add "save as everything as XML" to my bag of js tools

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for your most recent clarification, that you **must** have a string copy. Leaving it, though, for others who may have more flexibility.

---

Since using the DOM seems to allow you to preserve, to some degree, the invalid structure, and using `innerHTML` involves reparsing with (as you've observed) side-effects, we have to look at not using `innerHTML`:

You can clone the original, and then swap in the clone:

```
var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
snippet.log("1: " + e.innerHTML);
var clone = e.cloneNode(true);
var insert = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
insert.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(insert);
snippet.log("2: " + e.innerHTML);
e.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, e);
e = clone;
snippet.log("3: " + e.innerHTML);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
snippet.log("1: " + e.innerHTML);
var clone = e.cloneNode(true);
var insert = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
insert.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(insert);
snippet.log("2: " + e.innerHTML);
e.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, e);
e = clone;
snippet.log("3: " + e.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="asdf">
  <p id="outer">
    <div>ladygaga</div>
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that just like the `innerHTML` solution, this will wipe out event handlers on the elements in question. You could preserve handlers on the outermost element by creating a document fragment and cloning its children into it, but that would still lose handlers on the children.

---

This earlier solution won't apply to you, but may apply to others in the future:

My earlier solution was to track what you changed, and undo the changes one-by-one. So in your example, that means removing the `insert` element:

```
var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
console.log("1: " + e.innerHTML);
var insert = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
insert.appendChild(text);
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
outer.appendChild(insert);
console.log("2: " + e.innerHTML);
outer.removeChild(insert);
console.log("3: " + e.innerHTML);
```

```js
var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
snippet.log("1: " + e.innerHTML);
var insert = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
insert.appendChild(text);
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
outer.appendChild(insert);
snippet.log("2: " + e.innerHTML);
outer.removeChild(insert);
snippet.log("3: " + e.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="asdf">
  <p id="outer">
    <div>ladygaga</div>
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I have no control over how the DOM came to be that way. I just want to restore an exact copy. For more context, this is happening inside an extension, so it should work on any web page.

Comment: @SergiuToarca: Nothing in the answer said you had to change how the DOM came to be that way. Your context helps (useful to put context in the question!) -- e.g., you don't control the HTML **or** the code changing it.

Comment: @SergiuToarca: The good news is with the `cloneNode` solution, you don't have to.

Comment: Unfortunately, cloneNode won't work because the page needs to be restored after serialization/deserialization e.g. remotely. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Blob` , `URL.createObjectURL` to export `html` ; include `script` tag in exported `html` which removes `<div></div><p></p>` elements from rendered `html` document

html

```
<body>
    <div id="asdf">
        <p id="outer"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var insert = document.createElement("div");
        var text = document.createTextNode("ladygaga");
        insert.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById("outer").appendChild(insert);
        var elem = document.getElementById("asdf");
        var r = document.querySelectorAll("[id=outer] ~ *");
        // remove last `div` , `p` elements from `#asdf`
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; ++i) {
            elem.removeChild(r[i])
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

js

```
var e = document.getElementById("asdf");   
var html = e.outerHTML;  
console.log(document.body.outerHTML);   
var blob = new Blob([document.body.outerHTML], {
    type: "text/html"
});   
var objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var popup = window.open(objUrl, "popup", "width=300, height=200");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/11/

Comment: I have no control over the web page, so I don't know if element id `asdf` exists (on most pages it will not exist).

Answer (score 0):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/1Lcgaprc/

[MDN cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
console.log(e.innerHTML);
backupElem = e.cloneNode(true);
// Your tinkering with the original
e.parentNode.replaceChild(backupElem, e);
console.log(e.innerHTML);
```

Comment: This works if I can keep everything in memory, but the html must be serialized/deserialized before being restored.

Comment: @SergiuToarca you are using jquery in your project or not ? if yes then i have one solution

Comment: You can use any library you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can not expect HTML to be parsed as a non-compliant HTML. But since the structure of compiled non-compliant HTML is very predictable you can make a function which makes the HTML non-compliant again like this:

```
function ruinTheHtml() {

var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName( "*" ),
    next,
    afterNext;

Array.prototype.map.call( allElements,function( el,i ){

    if( el.tagName !== 'SCRIPT' && el.tagName !== 'STYLE' ) {

        if(el.textContent === '') {

            next = el.nextSibling;

            afterNext = next.nextSibling;

            if( afterNext.textContent === '' ) {

                el.parentNode.removeChild( afterNext );
                el.appendChild( next );

            }

        }

    }
});

}
```

See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pqah8e25/3/

Comment: This only works on my example. It should work on any webpage that I give you.

Comment: it should work on any non-compliant html since when you make an incorrect html it will always be parsed as <empty tag> <content which was in empty tag> <empty tag>. Can you give me a case where it doesn't work please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the node instead of copying html. Parsing rules will force the browser to close `p` when seeing `div`.

If you really need to get html from that string and it is valid xml, then you can use following code (`$` is `jQuery`):

```
var html = "<p><div></div></p>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
var xml = $.parseXML(html);
div.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
div.innerHTML === html // true
```

Comment: This does not work if the html contains `script` tags. As a reminder, this code should be able to work on any arbitrary web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outerHTML`, it perseveres the original structure:

(based on your original sample)

```
<div id="asdf"><p id="outer"></p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var insert = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode('ladygaga');
    insert.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(insert);
    var e = document.getElementById('asdf')
    console.log(e.outerHTML);
    e.outerHTML = e.outerHTML;
    console.log(e.outerHTML);
</script>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b2x7rnfm/7**

Comment: No, using `outerHTML` does not fix the problem. I've used your code and added a couple `console.log` that show it does not work. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqfh1sw2/2/). When you do `e.outerHTML = e.outerHTML`, the browser takes the node to which `e` refers and *replaces it with a new DOM node*. So after the assignment `e` is no longer in the DOM tree. The first `console.log` I added in the fiddle shows that. The second one shows that the DOM structure is what the OP is trying to avoid. `outerHTML` obeys the same parsing rules as `innerHTML`.