# Puppeteer: How to save the HTML code with its original HTML character encoding?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character-encoding, puppeteer

```
var html = await page.content();
```

is nice, so I can use `fs.writeFileSync()` to save that to a file.

Problem is, special HTML characters like `&reg;` are saved converted (to UTF-8 I suppose... probably depending on the page).

How can I save that code with its original HTML encoding?

I also tried to `resolve( document.documentElement.outerHTML )` from an evaluate() but of course that's what `page.content()` uses internally so it's encoded too.

NOTE: I made some modifications to various elements using evaluate() so I cannot just get the data again from the server, I need the current page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> index.html ↓

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  &reg;®
</body>
</html>
```

> index.js ↓

```js
(async () => {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    args: ['--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const response = await page.goto('file://index.html');
  const data = await response.buffer();
  const html = data.toString('utf8');
  console.log(html);
  /*
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    &reg;®
  </body>
  </html>
  */
})();
```

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is impossible, since rendering HTML to the DOM and then serializing it again (which is what happens every time you read `document.documentElement.outerHTML`) is a lossy process which doesn't track which symbols were originally encoded as HTML entities.  You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077690/restore-exact-innerhtml-to-dom).